# which control triggered this event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm triggering the same javascript function from 4 different Kendo dropdowns.  I would like to be able to tell which one of the dropdown is doint the triggering.  Here is the event call from just one of them (all four are the same) and the function.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("myDropdownListName")
      ......
      ......
      .Events(e => e.Change("aJavascriptFunction")))


function aJavascriptFunction() {
    alert(name of dropdown list or some other distinguishable thing here )
}
```

I assume it's something to do with the this keyword,  but don't know if the this keyword works in this situation.     Ideas.?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `e` to the event handler, and use its `currentTarget` property to determine which element triggered the event.

```
function aJavascriptFunction(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
}
```

**Update**:

Try to change the event binding to be of a template delegate type:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("myDropdownListName")
      ......
      ......
      .Events(e => e
          .Change(@<text>
              function(e) { 
                  aJavascriptFunction(e);
              }
           </text>
      )))
```

Comment: Thanks Catalyst but didn't exactly work.   Came back as "undefined"

Comment: @RickW., what happens when you do `console.log(e);`?

Comment: It says the same thing Catalyst,   undefined.

Comment: What if you include `this` in your `Change` call? `.Events(e => e.Change("aJavascriptFunction(this)")))`?

Comment: @RickW., please see my updated answer, there's another way of binding an event to a JavaScript function which might help.

Comment: Actually, i figured it out.   Instead of e.currentTarget,  it's e.sender.element[0].id ...     Thanks

Comment: Thanks Catalyst for pointing me in the right direction though

Comment: Sure, no problem, glad you figured it out :)